# My 4th gen ThinkPad X1 Yoga's keyboard & trackpad not deactivating

Tags: kubuntu, thinkpad, 20.04, tablet, yoga-2

My ThinkPad X1 Yoga isn't usable as a tablet.  Flipping it in tablet mode is not shutting the keyboard and trackpad off.  When it does work, I cannot re-enable the keyboard and trackpad.

Are there any packages I need to install to make it work properly?

Answer (score 0):

Lenovo says the Yoga BIOS design for Yoga machines precludes Linux install, so I'm not surprised. See Lenovo's own statement on the subject https://news.lenovo.com/pressroom/press-releases/lenovo-statement-on-linux-support-for-yoga/

Comment: According to [this page on Lenovo's support](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/pd031426), it should work